# rsync --update --> warn if local file is newer

Tags: rsync

We use `rsync --update` to update files from a server to a laptop.

The files on the laptop should not be modified.

But the laptop gets used by several people, so a newcomer might think he can change the files on the laptop.

To avoid overwrites we use `rsync --update`.

Is there a way to make rsync print out all files which were skipped because the local (laptop) file was updated?

I tried it with `rsync -auvz foo@server:bar .`

We use rsync version 3.1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

man rsync :

> -v, --verbose
>                 This option increases the amount of information you are given during the transfer.  By default, rsync works silently. A single
>   -v
>                 will  give  you  information  about  what files are being transferred and a brief summary at the end. Two -v options will
>   give you
>                 information on what files are being skipped and slightly more information at the end. More than two -v options should only be
>   used
>                 if you are debugging rsync.

You need to put -vv on your command to print all files which were skipped :)

Answer (score 5):

You could do this in two steps:

1. Copy while avoiding overwrites:

   `rsync -au foo@server:bar .`
2. List the remaining differences with `--dry-run` and `--itemize` (or `--itemize-changes`):

   `rsync --dry-run --itemize -a foo@server:bar .`